# CSS hack for issue of IE 6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

[image]

I have a HTML page where i have div to show help as shown in image above at bottom.

I also have combo box (select input) which is comming on top of this help div in IE 6.

For other browser and and IE6+ versions, it is working fine.

Is there any CSS hack for this issue for IE 6?

Comment: Do you *really* still need to support IE6? It has been considered obsolete for years already. MS still support it with security patches, but that will end in a year or so, after which it will be wide open to getting hacked. If your customer/boss is still asking for IE6, then you need to be telling them why it's a really bad idea.

Comment: We do not want to support IE 6, as a developer. But customer wants us to support that :)

Comment: Well, fair enough if you feel you need to take the work, but I hope you're charging them a lot extra for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very famous and old bug with IE6. What you need to do is to have an `iframe` before the `div`. This bug is quite well documented. It happens because in IE6 `select` boxes were ActiveX controls and were meant to be above all the elements of the page. `iframe` is also an ActiveX control and can be set above the `select` box. You can read up about the hack on this website http://www.javascriptjunkie.com/?p=5.

I am pretty sure a similar question has been asked around on SO as well but I couldn't find it.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15547/Fixing-Overlaying-Layers-with-Dropdowns-in-IE

Comment: @ChrisBentley, yeah that covers a few different ways of fixing it. Still wondering who uses IE6 in this day and age.

Comment: Staff at banks and other large enterprise outfits where their in-house legacy software works in no other browser.. :(

Answer (score 1):

There are well-documented CSS hacks for all the versions of IE.

For IE6, use the underscore hack -- put an underscore character at the front of the selector to target just IE6.

This page has full details: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/

Comment: @MichaelPeterson - yes, of course it is.  :-)  (note to self: don't answer questions when tired)

Comment: As far as I remember, the `_` hack won't work with the select boxes being below the `div`. I haven't tested or used IE6 for a while so it might have changed in the last couple of years but I think the fix is to use the `iframe` hack.

Comment: @sarcastyx - If you make the select box `display:none` using the hack, that should do it. The `iframe` hack is probably better, but involves quite significant changes to the underlying page structure. IE6 isn't worth that much effort any more.

Comment: @Spudley, oh IE6 is not worth a minute of effort any more. IE7 is a pain in the backside in itself let alone having to deal with IE6, IE7 and all the other incarnations of IE, FF, Chrome, Safari and what not.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, by default IE6 will put  above the other elements.

You could hide them **(display: none)** when this div.help is shown